# Can we use matrix to solve this inequality?

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&0\le x\le 1\\
0&\rm{others}
\end{cases}$$
Let $x_{i},a_{i}(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$ be positive real numbers,

show that:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f\left(\dfrac{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}{2}\right)\le 3\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f(|x_{i}-x_{j}|)$$

Comment: One observation: First note that we can assume $x_1\leq x_2\leq \ldots \leq x_n$ without loss of generality (we can interchange $x_i$ with $x_j$ if we also interchange $a_i$ with $a_j$ without changing the inequality). If we let $x_{ij} = |x_i-x_j|$ and if $i>j$ then we have
$$x_{i,j} = x_{i,i-1}+x_{i-1,i-2}+\ldots + x_{j+1,j}$$
From this we see that if $x_{i,j}\in(1,2]$ then at most one of the $i-j$ terms on the right hand side can be in $(1,2]$. This could perhaps be useful for constraining the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this is only a partial answer.

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f\left(\dfrac{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}{2}\right)\le 3\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f(|x_{i}-x_{j}|)$$

$$\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f\left(\dfrac{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}{2}\right)\le 3\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}f(|x_{i}-x_{j}|) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{i}$$

$$\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}\left(f\left(\dfrac{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}{2}\right)-3f(|x_{i}-x_{j}|)\right)\le 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{i}$$

If the $x_i$ are spread far out, such that all $|x_{i}-x_{j}|>2$, the lhs is $0$ and the inequality is trivial.

If the $x_i$ are packed together, such that all $|x_{i}-x_{j}|<1$, the lhs is negative and the inequality is trivial.

The question becomes interesting only if there are some $|x_{i}-x_{j}|$ between 1 and 2, for which 
$$\begin{matrix}f\left(\dfrac{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}{2}\right)-3f(|x_{i}-x_{j}|)=1& (1) \end{matrix}$$

When $n=2$, it is possible to choose $x_i$ such that (1) holds for all $i,j$, foe examle $x_1=1,x_2=3$. Then
$$\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{2}a_{i}a_{j}\le 2\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_{i}^2$$
$$2 a_{1}a_{1}\le 2 a_{1}^2 +  2 a_{2}^2$$
$$a_{1}a_{1}\le 2\frac{a_{1}^2 + a_{2}^2}{2}$$
By the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we have
$$\frac{a_{1}^2 + a_{2}^2}{2}\geq a_1 a_2$$
So the inequality holds at least for $n=2$.

As pointed out by Winther in comments, for $n>3$ it is not generally true that
$$\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}\le 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^2$$
The issue is that the lhs grows quadratically in $n$, while the rhs grows linearly in $n$.

However, when $n>3$ it is also not possible to select $x_i$ such that (1) holds for all of them. Likely, the largest number of pairs $(i,j)$ that obey (1) is $(n-1)$.

Comment: It is unfortunately not true that $\sum_{i\not= j} a_ia_j \leq 2\sum_i a_i^2$. Just take all $a_i$ to be equal $c$ to get $n(n-1)c^2 \leq 2nc^2$ which fails for $n>3$. Also if we did have $\ldots = 1$ for all $i\not=j$ then this would not be enough to prove the statement. Take $n=4$ as an example: the right hand side minus the left hand side in this case is $2a_1^2+2a_2^2+2a_3^2+2a_4^2 - 2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4)$ which for $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=c$ is $-4c^2 < 0$.